# How to set Photoshop File Associations via command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, adobe-photoshop, file-management

I am trying to re-associate .psd files with Photoshop CS6 via command line.

I feel like this should work.  But it is not.

```
assoc .psd=Photoshop.Image.13
ftype Photoshop.Image.13="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, **backup** all associations between file extensions and `FileType`s as well as links between `FileType`s and executable programs as follows:

```
ASSOC>assocbackup.txt
FTYPE>ftypebackup.txt
```

As both `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` commands are about to modify values under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` registry hive, you must be running in an elevated session to use them as follows:

Delete present association(s):

```
assoc .psd=
ftype Photoshop.Image.13=
```

Then note:

- [The FileType should always be created before making a File Association](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html)
- Define command line parameter(s), at least `"%1"`

The code (supposing your path to `Photoshop.exe` is right):

```
ftype Photoshop.Image.13="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe" "%1"
assoc .psd=Photoshop.Image.13
```